# What's kind of object use to do a form with a select field?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

In my model, I have this two classes `Sport` and `SportSession` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sport")
public class Sport implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="sport_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "sport_session")
public class SportSession implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="sport_session_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sport_id", nullable = false)
    private Sport sport;
    }
}
```

With Thymeleaf, I want to do a form allowing to create a `SportSession`.
I want this form contains a `<select>` field with the name of all the sports in order to associate a `Sport` to a `SportSession`.
My question is : How kind of object should be send from my controller to the view?
Should I create a new object `SportSessionForm` that contains the list of all the sports, and also a `Sport` member to store the sport selected by the user?
Is SportSession is sufficient to do that? And what about DTO object ?
In short, what is the best practice in this case?

Thanks already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to maintain two separate Beans one for the presentation layer (`SportSessionFormBean`) and Business/Entiry Bean (`SportSession`) for the Business tier (services layer).

You need to convert the presentation bean data (`SportSessionFormBean`) to the Business bean in the Controller classes and then pass that to Business Bean Object (`SportSession`)to the Services layer. Service layer uses this Business Bean to interact with DAO classes which persist or do some transactions with the database.

> How kind of object should be send from my controller to the view ?
>   Should I create a new object SportSessionForm that contains the list
>   of all the sports, and also a Sport member to store the sport selected
>   by the user?

Yes, SportSessionFormBean interacts with the HTML front end.

> Is SportSession is sufficient to do that? And what about DTO object ?
>   In short, what is the best practice in this case?

As explained above, do not mix up the presentation tier data with business tier (Services layer) data. Services are reusable components and they interact with multiple end points (like a controller or a different web service etc..).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! Suppose now I want to create a new page that list all SportSession. For each SportSession I would like to display "averageSpeed" that is neither in  business bean SportSession , nor in SportSessionFormBean, because his value is calculated according attributes "duration" and "distanceTravelled" . How can I handle that? Create a new member in SportSessionFormBean ? (but it is no longer a form in this case), or should I create an other object ?

Comment: Because it is a computation field to be displayed in FrontEnd, it needs to be in SportSessionFormBean, which is the main purpose of any FormBean. FormBean = BusinessBean (except any elements not to be shown/passed to Frontend for Security reasons) elements + add more attributes to be computed & displayed in FronEnd. A Single FormBean can interact with multiple similar html pages.